# When adding an integer to ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a very stupid question here. When we add an int value to an ArrayList, will it create a new Integer object of that int value?
For example:

```
int a = 1;
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(a);
```

In the code above, 'a' is a primitive type which has value 1, 'list' is an arraylist which contains elements of Integer type. So when adding 'a' to 'list', how does 'list' treat 'a' as an Integer?

Comment: [Autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `a` is [autoboxed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) to an `Integer`. From the link,

> *Autoboxing* is the automatic conversion that the Java compiler makes between the primitive types and their corresponding object wrapper classes.

Comment: so the compiler will create a new object in the heap, which has no relation to the variable a, it that correct?

Comment: Regardless of whether a new object is created (there must be a cache for values in the range of `byte`), the [`intValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#intValue--) will equal `a` so they're **related**. And, if unboxed, then the value will also equal `a`.

Answer (score 0):

Whether a new `Integer` object is created depends on the value if the `int` being added. The JVM has a cache of premade objects covering a range of common values, and if the value is in that range it will use the existing cached object instead of creating a new one.

For the `int` type, [the Java language specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7) requires that this cache cover all numbers from -128 to 127 (inclusive). A JVM implementation may or may not include additional values in this cache, at its option.

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

In

```
int a = 1;
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(a);
```

the last line is automatically converted by the compiler into:

```
list.add(Integer.valueOf(a));
```

`Integer.valueOf` is a method that either creates a new `Integer` object with the same value, or reuses one that already exists. The resulting object has no relation to the variable `a`, except that it represents the same value.

Comment: Thank you for answering, that helps me to understand